# C# - Windows firewall rule added using INetFwPolicy2 not in effect

Tags: c#, windows, windows-firewall

I'm writing a server programme running on Windows using the following code in C#.

```
Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
foreach (INetFwRule2 rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
{
    if (rule.Name == ruleName)
    {
        if (!rule.Enabled)
        {
            rule.Enabled = true;
        }
        return;
    }
}
INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
inboundRule.Enabled = true;
inboundRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
inboundRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
inboundRule.LocalPorts = "8080";
inboundRule.Name = ruleName;               // ruleName is the name of the assembly
inboundRule.ApplicationName = progName;    // progName is the full path to the executable
fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
```

This piece of code is able to add a firewall rule to Windows 10 that is displayed within Window 10 Firewall and Advanced Security dialogue. However, with this rule enabled, my application still can't listen to requests from other devices within the local network. It works only if the rule is a port rule that does not specify programmes allowed. How should I configure this such that the rule only allow my application to listen to network requests?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 INetFwRule firewallRule = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule")) as INetFwRule;
```

Comment: How have you defined INetFwRule?